# Reporting similarity between continuous variables

Tags: regression, machine-learning, statistical-significance, exploratory-data-analysis

I have two continuous variables. They have the same shape, but there is some time shift between them. In the following plot you see a line plot:the values (y) and time (X).
[image]

Which measure can I use to report this similarity. I looked at the Pearson and spearman correlation and I found that they gives low values like -0.087. ?

If this question does not belong to here, please move it to stats.stackexchange.com. Thanks

Comment: Please explain what you are showing in the plot.  Ordinarily, one would expect you to be describing the *distribution* of a random variable, but these obviously are neither distribution nor density functions.

Comment: You appear to describe *time series* rather than "continuous variables."  One important issue concerns the form of your data: most likely you are sampling some process at regular intervals of time--and that would lead to people recommending standard time-series procedures such as the ACF or PACF--but if the sampling is irregular, or triggered by other events, then possibly somewhat different solutions would be needed.  Could you therefore describe your data in the question?  In the meantime, since at least the nature of the question has become apparent, I will vote to reopen it.

Comment: whuber, I'm just wondering and please correct me. Since the plot looks to be smoothed, can Sharek not interpolate and use something like cross-correlation? Thank you.